# casting a generic (interface) to a type when all possible types have same methods

Tags: go

Take the method:

```golang
x509.CreateCertificate(rand.Reader, &template, &template, publicKey, privateKey)
```

looking at the defitiniton, both publicKey and privateKey here are type 'any'. I don't know at compile time which type of key a user will provide - and that *seems* fine as I can pass either in.

However, I am struggling with the handling of the `any` to either of these types of keys.

This was where I got to before I realised I might have a problem:

```golang
    var privKey any
    switch priv.(type) {
        case *ecdsa.PrivateKey:
            privKey = priv.(*ecdsa.PrivateKey)
        case *rsa.PrivateKey:
            privKey = priv.(*rsa.PrivateKey)
        default:
            return nil, nil, errors.New("no valid key type passed")

    }
    der, err := x509.CreateCertificate(rand.Reader, &template, &template, &privKey.PublicKey, priv)
```

I could move the `CreateCertificate` call inside the cases, but that seems copypasta. Whats the correct way to do this?

Comment: go into definition of `func CreateCertificate(rand io.Reader, template, parent *Certificate, pub, priv interface{})` you will see `priv` has to implement `crypto.Signer` interface and the interface has method `Public() PublicKey`.

Comment: You can do `priv.(crypto.Signer).Public()` to get the public key corresponding to priv.

Comment: excellent, thank you! thats the gold! Should have looked for an interface!

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments, the solution is that the private keys both adhere to the interface `crypto.Signer` which I missed.

Therefore can do `priv.(crypto.Signer).Public()`